# MapReduce to yarn Config conversion

Tags: hadoop

how do I change my MapReduce v1 configuration (eg number of slots) to yarn configuration (eg container virtual memory and virtual cpu)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no longer the concept of a "slot". Instead there are containers, and each container is configured to have a certain amount of RAM and virtual CPU. Go to http://tiny.cloudera.com/yarn-tuning for a detailed writeup on the conversion process.